# Wso2 ESB Integration with SFDC

Tags: wso2, sfdc, wso2-esb

I am integrating WSO2 ESB 4.8.1 with SFDC.

Using SFDC connector 1.0

In WSO2 i have written the code `<salesforce.logout/>`, according to WSO2 Documentation they say that it closes the current connection.

`<salesforce.logout/>` produces below soap message which i identified in WSO2 ESB log

```
TID: [0] [ESB] [2016-08-30 07:55:39,442] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  << "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:partner.soap.sforce.com"><soapenv:Header><urn:SessionHeader><urn:sessionId>00D17000000BPGr!AQcAQDIggW.ikXtsb0Ckm8c8pKKDlF_8QN42jL31WUa6hDLOdEeNIjrYsevKW0FeZLDzlrjcDLwMni_7gYaZgNfdN4zv9Cgj</urn:sessionId></urn:SessionHeader></soapenv:Header><soapenv:Body><urn:logout></urn:logout></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
```

But few times i am getting below error ***(INVALID_SESSION_ID: Invalid Session ID found in SessionHeader: Illegal Session. Session not found, missing session hash:)*** when `<salesforce.logout/>` is executed

```
TID: [0] [ESB] [2016-08-30 07:55:39,529] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  >> "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:sf="urn:fault.partner.soap.sforce.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><soapenv:Body><soapenv:Fault><faultcode>sf:INVALID_SESSION_ID</faultcode><faultstring>INVALID_SESSION_ID: Invalid Session ID found in SessionHeader: Illegal Session. Session not found, missing session hash: je59etMAEPM+m9VdYJb0AW==[\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2016-08-30 07:55:39,529] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  >> "This is expected, it can happen if the session has expired and swept away, or if the user logs out, or if its just someone trying to hack in. </faultstring><detail><sf:UnexpectedErrorFault xsi:type="sf:UnexpectedErrorFault"><sf:exceptionCode>INVALID_SESSION_ID</sf:exceptionCode><sf:exceptionMessage>Invalid Session ID found in SessionHeader: Illegal Session. Session not found, missing session hash: je59etMAEPM+m9VdYJb0AW==[\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2016-08-30 07:55:39,529] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  >> "This is expected, it can happen if the session has expired and swept away, or if the user logs out, or if its just someone trying to hack in. </sf:exceptionMessage></sf:UnexpectedErrorFault></detail></soapenv:Fault></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
```

Is it SFDC issue/WSO2 SFDC connector issue/WSO2 ESB configuration issue.?

For upsert operation we are using configkey attribute in entire project, below is the code

```
<salesforce.upsert configKey="sfdc_connection_dtls">
          <allOrNone>0</allOrNone>
          <allowFieldTruncate>0</allowFieldTruncate>
          <sobjects xmlns:sfdc="sfdc">{//sfdc:sObjects}</sobjects>
        </salesforce.upsert>
```

So when i use `<salesforce.logout/>` in the respective sequence, does it closes only the current connection which is available in sequence.? or it closes all connection which are existing.?

Where ever i am using salesforce.upsert(below is the skeleton code) can i use `<salesforce.logout/>` after salesforce.upsert call.?

```
<salesforce.upsert configKey="sfdc_connection_dtls">
       <!-- sobject goes here -->
</salesforce.upsert>
```

Looking forward for your help

Thanks,
Tejas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In WSO2 SFDC connector, there's a single SF connection created per flow per init configuration. Therefore, if you issue a logout, your subsequent requests will fail. It is not necessary to issue logout since the connection is anyway terminated at the end of the flow.